# Prove $\frac{|a+b| +|c+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}}\leq \sqrt{2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone advise me how to prove this inequality? Hints will suffice, thank you

$\frac{|a+b|+|c+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}}\leq \sqrt{2}$ with $ a,b,c,d $ real numbers.

Comment: Hint: $(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 2(x^2+y^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|a+b\right|+\left|c+d\right|=\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\left(c+d\right)^{2}}\leq\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^{2}+\left(a-b\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\left(c+d\right)^{2}+\left(c-d\right)^{2}}.$$